# Can I create my own cache in Java? not 3rd party framework?

Tags: java, caching

Does Java itself supports caching? Since I am not allowed to use 3rd party framework or library due to policy, I would like to create my own cache which can store database data. When I try to research via Google, I only see those JCS, EhCache, Hibernate, etc...
For example, this is caching for C#

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. There are lots of caches implemented in Java. You certainly can implement your own cache.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is implementing my own cache not easy like C#?

Comment: Given the proliferation of third party Java caching systems, and to the best of my knowledge; there is no specific equivalent to your linked C# functionality built-into Java. Java predates and is not the same as C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start creating your own cache system by implementing [Flyweigth Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). This can be done with a plain array or something more complex like a [`Map<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and probably using a [`ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

If you're working in a web application, then you may use [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) as cache since it's elements are shared across all the application, but be careful since your classes should not directly access to this class, instead access to it from a `Servlet` or another technology that helps you access to it.

Still, it's not a good idea to create your own cache system. It's better to use a cache from a library, which offers more options than just a basic giant concurrent `Map<K, V>` on memory.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and it is really helpful!. I have a quick question. Do you know why JAVA does not support easy cache class like C# does? I am still confused..

Comment: You are saying that implementing my own cache is not recommended due to complexity, right?

Comment: Adrian AFAIK C# supports cache for Asp.Net and MVC. In contrast, Java has `ServletContext` since I remember working with Java web application, which could be similar but it's not a real cache since its elements need to be removed manually and doesn't offer synchronization when adding/removing attributes. Also, I don't really wonder why is or there isn't a class called Cache in Java. If you understand how a cache should work, then you can create yours and Java offers you the basic elements to do so.